# Проблема с валидацией формы

Tags: php, javascript, yii2

Проблема в следующем: эту форму я вывожу в модальном окне и при некорректном вводе (т.е. срабатывает проверка) меня перебрасывает на страницу login.php, а не оставляет в модальном окне. Я так понимаю, проверку тоже через ajax делать?

Сама форма Login.php

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm;

$this->title = 'Login';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="site-login">
<h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>



<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'id' => 'login-form',
    'options' => ['class' => 'form-horizontal blabla'],
    'fieldConfig' => [
        'template' => "{label}\n<div class=\"col-lg-3\">{input}</div>\n<div class=\"col-lg-8\">{error}</div>",
        'labelOptions' => ['class' => 'col-lg-1 control-label'],
    ],
]); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'username')->textInput(['autofocus' => true, 'template' => "  <span class='input-group-addon'>@</span>"]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'password')->passwordInput() ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'rememberMe')->checkbox([
        'template' => "<div class=\"col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-3\">{input} {label}</div>\n<div class=\"col-lg-8\">{error}</div>",
    ]) ?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-11">
            <?= Html::submitButton('Login', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'login-button']) ?>
        </div>
    </div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Контроллер

```
public function actionLogin()
{
    if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
        return $this->goHome();
    }

    $model = new LoginForm();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) {
        return $this->goBack();
    }
    return $this->renderAjax('login', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

Модальное окно

```
<?
\yii\bootstrap\Modal::begin([
    'header'=>'',
    'id'=>'modal',
    'size'=>'modal-cm',
]);
echo "<div id='modalcontent'></div>";
?>
```

js

```
$('#modalButton').click(function() {
        $('#modal').modal('show')
        .find('#modalcontent')
        .load($(this).attr('value'));//вызываю стр. Login.php

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Да, отправляя форму без ajax валидации страница будет сразу перезагружаться. Но учитывая, что это форма входа на сайт - ajax валидацию использовать в ней крайне не рекомендую.

Можно повесить обработчик события на отправку формы с `event.preventDefault();`, а в зависимости от ответа сервера либо снова вставлять в `#modalcontent` форму входа, либо перенаправлять пользователя.